# C# - How to delete and update the to-do list computer with Model and List?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a to-do application with Model and List in C#. First of all, my code is as follows:

`Program.cs`:

```
List<Todo> todo = new List<Todo>();
string select;
while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Select: \n---------\n[1] Exit\n[2] List\n[3] Add\n[4] Delete");
    select = Console.ReadLine()!;
    switch (select)
    {
        case "1":
            exit();
            break;
        case "2":
            list();
            break;
        case "3":
            // add
            break;
        case "4":
            // delete
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("input 0-4 number");
            continue;
    }
}

void exit()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Goodbye...");
    Environment.Exit(0);
}

void list()
{
    if (todo.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var item in todo)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ID: {0}\nTitle: {1}\nDone: {2}", item.id, item.title, item.isCompleted);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("List is empty.");
    }
}

void add(List<Todo> todoList)
{
    return Todo(todo[].title)
}
```

`Todo.cs`:

```
internal class Todo
{
    public int? id { get; set; }
    public string? title { get; set; }
    public bool? isCompleted { get; set; }
    public Todo(int id, string title, bool isCompleted)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.isCompleted = isCompleted;
    }
}
```

Exit, add, list, delete and edit operations are required and I was only able to exit, add and list parts. How can I delete and edit? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to delete an item, first you need to ask the ID, or the title you want to delete.
Then once you have it, you can do :

```
Todo itemToDelete = todo.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.ID==selectedId);
if(itemToDelete!=null)
{
    todo.Remove(itemToDelete);
}
```

I also strongly advise to rename all, because having an object `Todo`, and a list `todo` will bring you to confusion, for exemple call your `List<Todo> listTodo`